# linking data to a post

Tags: discussion

Probably a noob question.   When I post a question, It is easier for the viewers to have some simplistic data to understand the problem.   Creating the data with the sample code is only feasible if it is relatively small.  With more complex questions the data needed is not easily entered as code.

E.g. When asking question on a pandas dataframe, the code needed to get some illustrative data for a complex operation is very long.

Is there a way to elegantly link the data to the question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've answered quite a few [pandas](/questions/tagged/pandas) questions, so I think I'm qualified to say that you **really** don't need to. There will be a sample DataFrame and a few lines (more than a dozen and I'd be concerned) of offending code to recreate a not-working example. Extracting those so is a *key* exercise to understanding (and solving!) problems.

An example, from your [earlier (motivating?) question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17020763/pandas-0-10-1-to-0-11-0-is-method):

Your code fragment (basically you said "this isn't working in 0.11"):

```
accurate_list = ['corr1', 'corr2', 'corr3']
x = df[~df.Classification.isin(accurate_list)]
df.ix[x.index,'A'] = df['Classification']  # you say it bugged out here
```

You didn't give an example, so I created a random DataFrame (actually I just had this one lying around already) which I thought may give me an example of the exception:

```
df = pd.DataFrame([[1,10,20,30], [1,40,50,60], [2,20,30,40],], columns=list('ABCD'))

x = df[~(df.A.isin([2]))]
df.ix[x.index, 'A'] = df['D']  # worked fine, no exception
```

*I couldn't replicate it, so I [posted](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17020763/pandas-0-10-1-to-0-11-0-is-method#comment24599370_17020763) as such as a comment.*

I guess I was really asking is:

> "What is different about your DataFrame to mine"?

I suspect that if you can answer that, you'll be able to come up with a better example which you can fit in a few lines... in doing so you may even find the answer to your question. :)

*But what we don't want is you linking to an external (Gb?) file... Please don't do that!*

Comment: Thanks... you are right.   Problem is that I cannot seem to recreate the problem with a small dataframe... also made a typo (since corrected), error is not exception, the wrong data is copied to the column.  Still trying various arrangements of data to see when it happens.   My original dataframe is 175 rows by 44 columns.   None of the smaller samples seem to recreate the error though.

Wrong place for further discussion on my other question though

Comment: I agree with hayden on keeping examples small. StringIO is a nice way for faking files in case the problem can only be replicated with functions like `pd.read_csv()`. If you really need to, hosting it somewhere allows you to create an example like:
`df = pd.read_csv(urllib2.urlopen('http://somedomain.pd/example.csv'))`
With the risk of dead links in the future, so definitely not recommended.

Comment: @RutgerKassies I favour just printing the DataFrame and then *we* can use `pd.read_clipboard`, so we both refer to it as read_csv (since it's really just a wrapper).